# Changing INT with FLOAT

Tags: c

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define n 3
#define m 3

int main(void)
{
int i;
int j;
int mat[n][m];
int sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("Enters the matrix values[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + mat[i][j];
    }
}

printf("the sum of all elements of matrix is: %d\n", sum);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + mat[i][j];
    }
    sum = sum / m;
    printf("The average of the i-th line is %d e': %d\n", i, sum);
}
getch();
}
```

This program works but if the result of sum is an odd number, the average of i-th line is approximated by default.

For solving it I have changed "int summ" with "float summ" but it doesn't work.

Can Someone help me please?

Comment: Solving what? You have just dumped some code here. How are we supposed to know what it does?

Comment: I think you need to be more concrete on what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Try `sum = sum / m;
    printf("The average of the i-th line is %d e': %d\n", i, sum);` --> `printf("The average of the i-th line is %d e': %.2f\n", i, (double)sum/m);`

Comment: solved, thank you all

Comment: this statement: `sum = sum / m;` is performing an integer divide.  So any fraction will be lost. suggest 1) `sum` be declared as `double` or `float`.  2) the format specifier in the call to `printf()` for `sum` be changed to `%.2f`

Answer (score 4):

It *would* work if you changed the *type* of `sum` to a `float` or `double`, *but* you'd also need to change the format specifier in your `printf` call. Use `%f` to output a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are printing a %d for sum in the end, which is used for int types. If you want the float to be printed correctly, you have to use %f.

Comment: You beat me to it, Bathsheba.